# How to browse mobile directory in flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I have captured 3 videos on my mobile which is by default stored on the phone gallery (Gallery/videos/). I have to play these 3 videos in one of my flex mobile application. How can I get the videos to the flex project? if I need to browse the mobile directory means kindly help me with some code to do so.

Comment: Do you want to show a dialog so the user can browse the directory?  Or do you want to browse the directory "in code" and show it to your users?  Do you already know the directory name/location or are you expecting to find it via code ?  Generically, you'll want to use the File class. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html and probably getDirectoryListing() or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. I dont know the directory name/location.. I just want to display the all the videos from the mobile gallery as a list..

Comment: Are you using flex or AIR?

Comment: @nakib Flex and AIR are not mutually exclusive.  For a Mobile App; he must be using AIR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too am looking for an answer to this question.  Right now, based on other Stackoverflow discussions, exhaustive perusal of tutorials and Adobe documentation, and comments to both (often the more useful resource), I'm coming to the conclusion that it's not possible.

- you can use CameraRoll.browseForImage() and open the iOS gallery of photos to see all entities of MediaType.IMAGE, but it will not show you MediaType.VIDEO
- you can use CameraUI to launch the system camera by delegation and that returns a MediaPromise, but as far as I can tell, it does not save the video you capture anywhere, and I cannot find a way to access the captured video using the MediaPromise (at least using the Loader class)

Here's my code as a hint in that direction.  The second code block is using the CameraRoll to browseForImage() but there is no browseForVideo() in the API.

```
if(CameraUI.isSupported)
{
    camera = new CameraUI();

    camera.addEventListener(MediaEvent.COMPLETE,    videoMediaEventComplete);
    camera.addEventListener(Event.CANCEL,           cameraCanceled);
    camera.addEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR,       cameraError);

    camera.launch(MediaType.VIDEO);
}
else
{
    statusText.text = "Camera not supported on this device.";
    startTimer();
}


if (CameraRoll.supportsBrowseForImage)
{
    roll = new CameraRoll();

    roll.addEventListener(MediaEvent.SELECT,    cameraRollEventComplete);
    roll.addEventListener(Event.CANCEL,         cameraCanceled);
    roll.addEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR,     cameraError);

    roll.browseForImage();
}
else
{
    statusText.text = "Camera roll not supported on this device.";
    startTimer();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've since found that Videos captured using the delegated system camera are stored in a temporary storage location that iOS -DOES!- allow access to.  (I was pleasantly shocked.)

The Captured video is not added to the device's Camera Roll as other videos captured using the iOS System Camera app, so it's not enough to capture video and expect to be able to access it later (if, for instance, CameraRoll.browseForVideo() is ever added to the API.

Therefore, you have to 'get while the getting is good' and move the file from the temporary storage location to some non-volatile location such as ApplicationStorageDirectory or the user's Documents directory (The only options in iOS I think).

The MediaPromise... I think... is completely useless for accessing the video via any direct progressive loader/streamer method, but still provides the location/url/path/filename of the temporary file so you can perform File operations on it.

Ironic that there are tutorials for getting around the lack of a file location/url/path/filename in the MediaPromise when using CameraRoll.browseForImage()... and that method is to use a loader class to load the image content (which you can then write out to a file), but when taking video, the video content is not accessible, and instead a file location/url/path/filename is provided. Ironic that there are nearly no resources I was able to find to help with this also. *grumble*

I'm going to include some code chunks w/o really editing them to strip out extraneous bits because it's way past when I need to be in bed, but I wanted you to have this.  I may come clean it up later.

This section is in a Spark SkinnablePopUpContainer and I use the same click event for several buttons, thus the below 'case' is in the switch-case in that event handler function.

In case you are not familiar, the 'close(true, data)' is the method to close the SkinnablePopUpContainer, tell the parent/owner that the container was closed purposefully and that it should look for the data object being shared back (i.e., there are changes to be 'commit'ed).

```
case "cameraVideo":
{
    if(CameraUI.isSupported)
    {
        camera = new CameraUI();
        camera.addEventListener(MediaEvent.COMPLETE,     videoMediaEventComplete);
        camera.addEventListener(Event.CANCEL,            cameraCanceled);
        camera.addEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR,        cameraError);
        camera.launch(MediaType.VIDEO);
    }
    else
    {
        statusText.text = "Camera not supported on this device.";
        startTimer();
    }
    break;
}

protected function cameraCanceled(event:Event):void
{
    statusText.text = "Camera access canceled by user.";
    startTimer();
}

protected function cameraError(event:ErrorEvent):void
{
    statusText.text = "There was an error while trying to use the camera.";
    startTimer();
}

protected function videoMediaEventComplete(event:MediaEvent):void
{
    statusText.text="Preparing captured video...";

    camera.removeEventListener(MediaEvent.COMPLETE,     videoMediaEventComplete);
    camera.removeEventListener(Event.CANCEL,    cameraCanceled);
    camera.removeEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR,        cameraError);

    var media:MediaPromise = event.data;

    data.MediaType = MediaType.VIDEO;
    data.MediaPromise = media;
    data.source = "camera video";

    close(true,data)
}
```

This section is the Actionscript in the close handler of the parent/owner of the SkinnablePopUpContainer (truncated once the useful code is included)

```
private function choosePictureLightboxClosed(event:PopUpEvent):void
{
    imageButtonsActive = false;

    if(event.commit)
    {
        this.data = event.data as Object;

        filters = new Array();
        selection = true;

        switch(data.MediaType)
        {
            case MediaType.VIDEO:
            {
                mediaType = "video"; 

                trace(data.MediaPromise.file.url  + " - " + data.MediaPromise.relativePath + " - " +data.MediaPromise.mediaType);

                var sourceFile:File = new File(data.MediaPromise.file.url);
                var destinationFile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("User" +parentApplication.userid);

                if(destinationFile.exists && !destinationFile.isDirectory)
                {
                    destinationFile.deleteFile();
                }
                destinationFile.createDirectory();

                destinationFile = destinationFile.resolvePath("Videos");
                if(destinationFile.exists && !destinationFile.isDirectory)
                {
                    destinationFile.deleteFile();
                }
                destinationFile.createDirectory();

                destinationFile = destinationFile.resolvePath(parentApplication.userid+"Video"+new Date().getTime()+".mov");
                trace(destinationFile.nativePath);

                sourceFile.moveTo(destinationFile,true);

                break;
            }
```

I sure do hope this helps.  This has been a very frustrating (and costly in terms of our project being government grant funded and having deadlines we utterly failed to meet), and I very much hope that these hard-won solutions might help others avoid the same experience.